# Java 8 avoiding null pointer checks using Optional

Tags: java, java-8, option-type, null-check

Is it possible to write something like this and to avoid checking if elements are not null and collections not empty:

```
 response.getBody()
    .getRequestInformation()
    .getRequestParameters().get(0)
    .getProductInstances().get(0)
    .getResultParameters()
```

I found something like this 
http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/03/15/avoid-null-checks-in-java/

Basically, what I want to achieve is to avoid if statement with multiple checking weather object is null or collection is empty in the hierarchy. I read in the post from my above that this is possible with Optional "Null checks are automatically handled under the hood."

If there is some solution already, sorry for making duplicate and please refer me to it.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? If this has to do with a new API in Java 9, you have to be specific about it.

Comment: Which part of http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/03/15/avoid-null-checks-in-java/ do you have a problem with? Either do a chain of `Optional.map` or catch NPE/AIOOBE.

Comment: Sorry, not java 9, typo :)

Comment: There's no way to write exactly what you wrote, short of wrapping the whole thing in a `try`/`catch`.
To use `Optional`, you need to assure the methods you call actually do return `Optional`, or wrap with `Optional.of` in every step. Then, you could chain the `map` calls like in the example you linked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to chain `Optional`, you can use its [`map(Function<? super T,? extends U> mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method to call the mapper function only if it is not `null` and use `flatMap(Stream::findFirst)` to get the first element of your `Collection` as next:

```
Optional<List<ResultParameterClass>> parameters = Optional.ofNullable(response)
    .map(ResponseClass::getBody)
    .map(BodyClass::getRequestInformation)
    .map(RequestInformationClass::getRequestParameters)
    .map(Collection::stream)
    .flatMap(Stream::findFirst)
    .map(RequestParameterClass::getProductInstances)
    .map(Collection::stream)
    .flatMap(Stream::findFirst)
    .map(ProductInstanceClass::getResultParameters);
```

---

> Is it possible to return the list if present in `Optional`, or if not
>   present then return something like new
>   `ArrayList<ResultParameterClass>()`?

Yes it is, you simply need to use [`orElseGet(Supplier<? extends T> other)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-) or [`orElse(T other)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) to provide **a default value**, the result won't be an `Optional` anymore but a `List<ResultParameterClass>`.

So the code would then be:

```
List<ResultParameterClass> parameters = Optional.ofNullable(response)
    ...
    .map(ProductInstanceClass::getResultParameters)
    .orElseGet(ArrayList::new);
```